# How to convert protocol buffers binary to JSON using the descriptor in Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a message with a field of the "Any" well known type which can hold a serialized protobuf message of any type.

I want to convert this field to its json representation.

I know the field names are required, and typically you would need the generated classes loaded in the app for this to work, but I am looking for a way to do it with the descriptors.

First, I parse the descriptors:

```
 FileInputStream descriptorFile = new FileInputStream("/descriptor");
DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet fdp = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(descriptorFile);
```

Then, loop through the contained messages and find the correct one (using the "Any" type's URL, which contains the package and message name. I add this to a TypeRegistry which is used to format the JSON.

```
JsonFormat.TypeRegistry.Builder typeRegistryBuilder = JsonFormat.TypeRegistry.newBuilder();

String messageNameFromUrl = member.getAny().getTypeUrl().split("/")[1];

for (DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto file : fdp.getFileList()) {
    for (DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto dp : file.getMessageTypeList()) {
        if (messageNameFromUrl.equals(String.format("%s.%s", file.getPackage(), dp.getName()))) {

            typeRegistryBuilder.add(dp.getDescriptorForType()); //Doesn't work.
            typeRegistryBuilder.add(MyConcreteGeneratedClass.getDescriptor()); //Works

            System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().usingTypeRegistry(typeRegistryBuilder.build()).preservingProtoFieldNames().print(member.getAny()));
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that parsing the descriptor gives me access to `Descriptors.DescriptorProto` objects, but I see no way to get the `Descriptors.Descriptor` object needed for the type registry. I can access the concrete class's descriptor with getDescriptor() and that works, but I am trying to format the JSON at runtime by accessing a pre-generated descriptor file from outside the app, and so I do not have that concrete class available to call `getDescriptor()`

What would be even better is if I could use the "Any" field's type URL to resolve the `Type` object and use that to generate the JSON, since it also appears to have the field numbers and names as required for this process.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I also tried using `DynamicMessage` to parse the Any, but that also requires passing in a `Descriptors.Descriptor` which I can't seem to get from the `Descriptors.DescriptorProto`

Answer (score 2):

If you convert a `DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto` to `Descriptors.FileDescriptor`, the latter has a `getMessageTypes()` method that returns `List<Descriptor>`.

Following is a snippet of Kotlin code taken from an open-source library I'm developing called [okgrpc](https://github.com/asarkar/okgrpc). It's the first of its kind attempt to create a dynamic gRPC client/CLI in Java.

```
private fun DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.resolve(
        index: Map<String, DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto>,
        cache: MutableMap<String, Descriptors.FileDescriptor>
): Descriptors.FileDescriptor {
    if (cache.containsKey(this.name)) return cache[this.name]!!

    return this.dependencyList
        .map { (index[it] ?: error("Unknown dependency: $it")).resolve(index, cache) }
        .let {
            val fd = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(this, *it.toTypedArray())
            cache[fd.name] = fd
            fd
        }
}
```